# how to write angular unit test cases with set @Input and mock it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-test

I'm new to Angular and currently learning to write the testcases. How should I write unit test cases for the following in angular/TypeScript?

```
@Input() set myOutputData(res: any) {
        this.apiError = '';
        if (!res) {
            this.myTableData = {
                opt: [],
                firstSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                secondSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                cost: 0
            };
            return;
        } else if (res && Object.keys(res).length === 0) {
            this.myTableData = {
                opt: [],
                firstSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                secondSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                cost: 0
            };
            return;
        } else if (this.errorTable) {
            const msg = 'message';
            this.apiError = this.errorTable;
            this.localError = this.apiError;
            this.myTableData = {
                opt: [],
                firstSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                secondSummary: { netSummary: [], new_summary: '' },
                cost: 0
            };
            return;
        } else {
            this.myTableData = res;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TestComponent` and inside that call your component which you want to test and pass input properties in that.

like this

```
@Component({
  template: '<your-component [myOutputData]="myOutputData"></your-component>'
})
export class TestComponent{    
  myOutputData = <value you want to pass>    
}
```

than write test cases for  `TestComponent` inside it access your component using `ViewChild` and test as per your need